# Check if index of List<List<string>> is not null

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I have a `List<List<string>>`, and a `ComboBox` with 10 items and when the selected index is changed, I use the `comboBox_selectedIndexChanged` event to bind the data for this index into a `ListBox`.

I also have `Add` and `Remove` buttons that can insert data to my `List<List<string>`.

How can I prevent the user from selecting index 5 from the `ComboBox` and add data for it, if the first four are still empty? E.g. tell him that he has to put data in indexes 1, 2, 3 and 4 first.

The click event for the `Add` button looks like this:

```
int selectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

//This throws an exception when the selected index is zero, 
//of course it makes sense because we can't check if index 0-1 in myList is null

if (myList.Count >= selectedIndex && myList[selectedIndex - 1] != null)
{
    myList[selectedIndex].Add(textEdit1.Text);
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Please fill the previous indexes first.");
```

I know that I can do it in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `ComboBox`, but I prefer to do it here.

Comment: I will always try to avoid using a `List` of `List` whenever possible. It will get really messy throughout your code. I suggest you converting your inner `List` to a `class`, that way you will have a `List` of `object` instead of `List` of `List`. Just IMO

Comment: Could you use a try:catch for a specific error?

Comment: Also, we need more information from your code. Is the `myList` refers to the "outer" `List` ot the "inner" `List`?

Comment: @CJ You are right, I've changed it to a List<List<MyClass>>, it's still a mess but I can't think of a better way..

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
int selectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
if (selectedIndex == 1 || (myList.Count >= selectedIndex && myList[selectedIndex - 1] != null))
{
    myList[selectedIndex].Add(textEdit1.Text);
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Please fill the previous indexes first.");
```

if selectedIndex == 1 is true then it wont test the second parameter in the if statement, and won't throw an error. If it is not 1 it will test the second parameter and your error will not be thrown.